# Trigger é executada somente após fechar a aplicação (JPA)

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, postgresql, jpa, trigger

Eu possuo a seguinte Trigger no meu Banco:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE function calcula_avaliacao_fisica()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    UPDATE avaliacao_fisica SET imc = calcula_imc(NEW.peso, NEW.altura/100) WHERE codigo = NEW.codigo;
    UPDATE avaliacao_fisica SET percentual_gordura = calcula_percentual_gordura(NEW.peso, NEW.peso_gordura) WHERE codigo = NEW.codigo;
    UPDATE avaliacao_fisica SET percentual_massa_magra = calcula_percentual_gordura(NEW.peso, NEW.peso_massa_magra) WHERE codigo = NEW.codigo;

    RETURN NEW;
END
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;

CREATE TRIGGER calcula_avaliacao_fisica AFTER INSERT ON avaliacao_fisica
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE calcula_avaliacao_fisica();
```

A ideia dela é calcular alguns atributos da minha tabela de avaliações físicas.

Além disso, tenho o meu método de inserir utilizando JPA:

```
public void inserir(AvaliacaoFisica avaliacao) {
    EntityManager em = this.emf.createEntityManager();
    
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.persist(avaliacao);
    em.getTransaction().commit();

    em.close();
}
```

O problema que estou encontrado é que a trigger executa somente após eu fechar minha aplicação.

Por exemplo, eu realizo o cadastro de uma nova avaliação física e após esse cadastro solicito a exibição da mesma. Quando eu for visualizar essa avaliação, o IMC (exemplo) estará com o valor padrão de 0.

No entanto, após eu encerrar o build da minha aplicação, buildar novamente e solicitar a exibição da mesma avaliação física, os dados apareceram calculados corretamente.

Alguém tem ideia de como resolver esse erro? Parece que o JPA executa as trigger's somente após encerrar a execução.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema era Cache!

Desativei o cache do JPA mudando essa propriedade no persistence.xml:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Leandro, sua resposta resolveu seu problema e aparentemente está correta, por favor, classifique-a como tal para que outras pessoas da comunidade possam se beneficiar disso no futuro.